# @JsonAnySetter, @JsonAnyGetter with DSL Json (De)/Serialization not taking values(always null)

Tags: json, annotations, jackson, dsl

Im using @JsonAnySetter and @JsonAnyGetter in my POJO class using my Custom serialization with DSL JSON class, the Map is initialized but the other properties are always null.
My POJO class:

```
  @CompiledJson
  public class Name {

String name;
public String getName() {
    return name;
}

public void setName(String name) {
    this.name = name;
}

Map<String,String> properties = new HashMap<String,String>();


public Name() {
    // TODO Auto-generated constructor stub
}

@JsonAnyGetter
public Map<String, String> get() {
    return this.properties;
}

@JsonAnySetter
public void set(String key, String value) {
    this.properties.put(key, value);
}
```

De/Serializing using DSLJson serialize() and deserialize() methods. I do not see any error also, but properties remains null in JSON. I doubt if Jackson annotations are supported by DSL Json. :/

Spring Boot App with DSL Json and Jackson Annotations

**UPDATE**
I want to parse MyClass, which is a part of RootClass:

```
 @Compiledjson
 public class RootClass {

private String id;
private List<MyClass> myclass;
private AnotherCLass class2;

//getters and setter here
}

 @CompiledJson
 public class MyClass implements JsonObject {

 private String name;

 private Map<String, String> properties; //want this to behave like Jackson's       @JsonAnySetter/Getter annotation.
 //The implementation of MapConverter serializer you mentioned below.
}
```

The entire code parses through custom Message reader and writer.

While sending my JSON Body, It'll be like this :

```
{
"id" : "1234",
"myclass" :
[
{
"name" : "abcd",
//any dynamic properties I want to add will go here
 "test" : "test1",
 "anything" : "anything"
}
],
"class2" : "test5"
}
```

Thank you :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

DSL-JSON doesn't support such get()/set(string, string) method pairs.
It does understand Map<String, String> so if you expose `properties` it will work on that. But not in this kind of setup.

As of v1.1 you have two options for solving such problems, both of them are covered in [example project](https://github.com/ngs-doo/dsl-json/blob/51f32ab70ba5a85faf846930d474e1a3fc7f74bb/examples/Maven/src/main/java/com/dslplatform/maven/Example.java#L70)

If you wish to reuse existing converters, your solution can look like this:

```
public static class MyClass {

    private String name;
    private Map<String, String> properties;

    @JsonConverter(target = MyClass.class)
    public static class MyClassConverter {
        public static final JsonReader.ReadObject<MyClass> JSON_READER = new JsonReader.ReadObject<MyClass>() {
            public MyClass read(JsonReader reader) throws IOException {
                Map<String, String> properties = MapConverter.deserialize(reader);
                MyClass result = new MyClass();
                result.name = properties.get("name");
                result.properties = properties;
                return result;
            }
        };
        public static final JsonWriter.WriteObject<MyClass> JSON_WRITER = new JsonWriter.WriteObject<MyClass>() {
            public void write(JsonWriter writer, MyClass value) {
                MapConverter.serialize(value.properties, writer);
            }
        };
    }
}
```

Comment: This is my JSON object: `"name" :  [
{
"name" : "test",
"test" : "testProps"
}
] ` this gives me this error - Expecting '{' at position 92. Found ". Also my variables are not final. How shall I change my JSON object? Also, my name object is a part of another object, like this - `{
"Obj1" : "1221111",
"SomeObj" :[
{
"someID" : "123456",
"name" :  [
{
"name" : "123334",
"test" : "test"
}
]
}
]
}`

Comment: I just wrote an example of implementation, feel free to change it. If you need to use it as array '[' you'll have to use converter. JsonObject must start with a '{'. This implementation expects "name": {. Update your question with more info and I can change implementation to parse that.

Comment: Updated my question!

Comment: Thank you so much :) Can you please explain how JSONConverter works? And why we dont need to use @CompiledJson annotation for this class?

Comment: CompiledJson is used for instructing compiler to build converters based on class structure. JsonConverter is used to instruct  compiler you have your own converters for specific class.